# Fixed positioning in Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, mobile-safari

Is it possible to position an element fixed relative to the viewport in Mobile Safari? As many have noted, `position: fixed` doesn't work, but Gmail just came out with a solution that almost is what I want – see the floating menu bar on the message view.

Getting real-time scroll events in JavaScript would also be a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

iOS 5 has [support for position:fixed](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/new-mobile-safari-stuff-in-ios5-position-fixed-overflow-scroll-new-input-type-support-web-workers-ecmascript-5).

Comment: Saw that this morning. Finally!

Comment: What about other mobile devices not on iOS?

Comment: @danwellman, I believe browser is called Mobile Safari in iOS only.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? There are still many users on lower versions of iOS fore one reason because of the missing support for there device..

Comment: @NickGreen - because it works for iOS 5, we expect users to throw their old devices in the bin, something you have to do with Apple as most software doesn't work on older phones.

Comment: If you use position:fixed as of IOS 5.1.1 (or earlier), you're likely in for a world of pain.  It's buggy.  Very buggy.

Comment: I've found this http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/17406/css-positionfixed-not-working-in-ipod/p1

Answer (score 74):

This fixed position div can be achieved in just 2 lines of code which moves the div on scroll to the bottom of the page.

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  document.getElementById('fixedDiv').style.top =
     (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - 25) + 'px';
};
```

Comment: Doesn't this present a bit of a delay?

Comment: onscroll isn't fired until _after_ the scrolling is completed, so the element would scroll with the page and then snap to the bottom when scrolling is done.

Comment: To add to this, mobile Safari now supports hardware accelerated transforms. So element.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(0, " + window.pageYOffset + "px, 0)"; will actually execute faster and less choppy than setting the top value.

Comment: @Adam: Don't know why but that didn't worked for me. The element doesn't showed up at all. Before it had `position:fixed;top:50%;left:50%;`.

Answer (score 10):

See [Google's solution to this problem](https://web.archive.org/web/20141001100814/https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/webapp_fixed_ui). You basically have to scroll content yourself using JavaScript. [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) also provides a library for getting this behavior in a very performant manor.

Comment: Link is outdated. Try https://web.archive.org/web/20141001100814/https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/webapp_fixed_ui

Answer (score 6):

it worked for me:

```
function changeFooterPosition() {   
  $('.footer-menu').css('top', window.innerHeight + window.scrollY - 44 + "px");
}

$(document).bind('scroll', function() {
  changeFooterPosition();
});
```

(44 is the height of my bar)

Although the bar only moves at the end of the scroll...

Answer (score 5):

This may interest you. It's Apple Dev support page. 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2010/tn2262/ 
Read the point "**4. Modify code that relies on CSS fixed positioning**" and you will find out that there is very good reason why Apple made the conscious decision to handle fixed position as static.

Comment: deep link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2010/tn2262/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009577-CH1-DontLinkElementID_5

Comment: There's no "very good reason" given at that link. All that is attempted is a description of the current situation.

Answer (score 4):

I think gmail just tracks the scroll position on a timer and repositions a `div` accordingly.

The best solution I've seen is at [doctyper](http://doctyper.com/archives/200808/fixed-positioning-on-mobile-safari/).

A simpler jQuery solution that moves an element onscroll: [link](http://markmail.org/message/c36au6ogcpyysit5)

Comment: How do you get the scroll position, then?

Comment: I've added the simpler method that tracks onscroll. Feel free to dig through jQuery to find the exact method to use; it might be window.pageYOffset but I'm not certain

Comment: The Problem with doctyper is that the phone responsiveness starts to lag when there is too much content to scroll ...

Answer (score 3):

You could try using touch-scroll, a jQuery plugin that mimics scrolling with fixed elements on mobile Safari: https://github.com/neave/touch-scroll

View an example with your iOS device at http://neave.github.com/touch-scroll/

Or an alternative is iScroll: http://cubiq.org/iscroll

Comment: I used both. Both work well. iScroll 4 is more thorough if you need more than just scroll control (ie fixed positioning.) Touch Scroll is limited and smaller.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i did it.
I have a nav block that is below the header once you scroll the page down it 'sticks' to the top of the window.
If you scroll back to top, nav goes back in it's place
I use position:fixed in CSS for non mobile platforms and iOS5.
Other Mobile versions do have that 'lag' until screen stops scrolling before it's set.

```
// css
#sticky.stick {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

// jquery 
//sticky nav
    function sticky_relocate() {
      var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
      var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;

      if (window_top > div_top)
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
      else
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
     }

$(window).scroll(function(event){

    // sticky nav css NON mobile way
       sticky_relocate();

       var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // sticky nav iPhone android mobile way iOS<5

       if (navigator.userAgent.match(/OS 5(_\d)+ like Mac OS X/i)) {
            //do nothing uses sticky_relocate() css
       } else if ( navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ) {

            var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
            var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;

            if (window_top > div_top) {
                $('#sticky').css({'top' : st  , 'position' : 'absolute' });
            } else {
                $('#sticky').css({'top' : 'auto' });
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Also making sure `height=device-height` is not present in this meta tag helps prevent additional footer padding that normally would not exist on the page. The menubar height adds to the viewport height causing a fixed background to become scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see what (mobile) browsers support css position fixed + there version.

http://caniuse.com/css-fixed

Answer (score 0):

Our web app requires a fixed header.  We are fortunate in that we only have to support the latest browsers, but Safari's behavior in this area caused us a real problem.

The best fix, as others have pointed out, is to write our own scrolling code.  However, we can't justify that effort to fix a problem that occurs only on iOS.  It makes more sense to hope that Apple may fix this problem, especially since, as QuirksMode suggests, Apple now stands alone in their interpretation of "position:fixed".

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2013/12/position_fixed_1.html

What worked for us is to toggle between "position:fixed" and "position:absolute" depending on whether the user has zoomed.  This replaces our "floating" header with predictable behavior, which is important for usability.  When zoomed, the behavior is not what we want, but the user can easily work around this by reversing the zoom.

```
// On iOS, "position: fixed;" is not supported when zoomed, so toggle "position: absolute;".
header = document.createElement( "HEADER" );
document.body.appendChild( header );
if( navigator.userAgent.match( /iPad/i ) || navigator.userAgent.match( /iPhone/i )) {
    addEventListener( document.body, function( event ) {
        var zoomLevel = (( Math.abs( window.orientation ) === 90 ) ? screen.height : screen.width ) / window.innerWidth;
        header.style.position = ( zoomLevel > 1 ) ? "absolute" : "fixed";
    });
}
```