# Fixed position on a mobile browser for footer

Tags: javascript, css, footer

Good day, i have a meta like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalabale=no, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
```

Now i can get the height view port with js
i want to use it to modify my footer so it stays always at the bottom of the screen using either a fixed positioning. here is the footer css

```
#footer
{
height:30px;
background-color:#D9D9D9;
background-image:url(../images/footer.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
margin-top:20px;
width:100%;
/*bottom:0;
position:fixed;*/
}
```

how do i modify this footer using JS to get the right thing. Thank you.
@cyberomin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("footer").style.position = "fixed";
```

Comment: yes this does not work, i want to use the view port's height to fix the footer, any tip.

Comment: @Cyberomin, .style.bottom = "0px";

Answer (score 1):

See also Google's solution to this 
http://code.google.com/mobile/articles/webapp_fixed_ui.html

Answer (score 0):

If you by mobile browser mean "mobile safari", you're out of luck, it does not support position fixed.

Related answer: [Fixed positioning in Mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743123/fixed-positioning-in-mobilesafari)

Edit: This project might be helpful for you -> http://cubiq.org/iscroll

Answer (score 0):

The position:fixed is available since Android 2.2.

However for other devices like IPhone, you must have a solution that simulates the native scroller : this type of solution is available through the JavaScript toolkit **[Wink](http://www.winktoolkit.org/)**. This toolkit allows to make WebApps easily while remaining simple to use (no need to learn an API). Look at the examples on the Scroller component.