# Fixed position not working on ipad

Tags: html, css, ipad, safari

We have developed a small control that is always meant to be at the bottom of the screen on out site. However when I view the site on the ipad the control does not stick to the bottom it floats in the middle.

Whats the deal with fixed position on the ipad? Is it not possible?

Does the ipad use safari mobile?

Comment: without code it's not possible to help at all ;-).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixed positioning in Mobile Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743123/fixed-positioning-in-mobile-safari)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should read [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/12/the_fifth_posit.html).

Comment: any reason for the downvote? (the iPad is running mobile safari so it's affected too)

Comment: I have no idea about the downvote maybe because of the short reply. Thanks though i will upvote you to make up :-)

Comment: @pete thx! - the article is already quite lengthy, check in particular the 2 different viewport concepts.

Comment: I would say the down-vote is on account of the barely visible link - I nearly down-voted you too until I looked closely and saw that "this" IS your link. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS 5.0, position:fixed is also implemented on the iPad: http://caniuse.com/css-fixed, though there are other problems, see [Disable scrolling when changing focus form elements ipad web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740253/disable-scrolling-when-changing-focus-form-elements-ipad-web-app) .

Answer (score 1):

Fixed header/footers for mobile devices are tricky. Using fixed positioning doesn't work as explained in the article posted to this thread by Knu.

I've found two solutions that should provide some relief. One is with [jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html) and the other is [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4). Both allow for fixed footer/headers.

My problem is that I'm having a hard time combing the fixed scrolling with other effects in the iPad. I hope this helps.