# Position fixed is not working on ipad

Tags: css

I am trying to fix the background of my website and i have place a div "bgDiv" on my website having position fixed. It is working good on desktop. but on ipad position fixed is not working it scrolls with my whole website. and background image is repeating. is there any way to avoid scrolling the bgDiv.

```
 .bgDiv{
    background: url("test.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -2;
    height: inherit;
    }

<body>
  <div class="bgDiv"></div>
     <div class="wrapper">
          content
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408363/fixed-position-not-working-on-ipad?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Update your css with this,

```
.bgDiv{
    background: url("test.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -2;
    height: auto;
    width:100%;
 }
```

If not added, add this to your code above,

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

You can refer to this documentation:-
http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/12/the_fifth_posit.html

Comment: I have already added this meta tag but its not working. thanks