# Fixed side nav on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, fixed

I am trying to get a site with a fixed side nav working on the iPad. I realized that iPad doesn't support position:fixed very well, so the side nav just scrolls up with the rest of the page. Is there a decent workaround for this? There is no time to redesign the site for iPad before the launch.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889601/css-position-fixed-into-ipad-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a fixed position, but you have to make sure that the meta-tags are set correctly.
Example:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```