# javascript (iscroll4) scrolling solution for webview in ios4 overrules/disables native gesture-recognition

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios4, css-position, iscroll4

In my iPad app I have a UIScrollView (a horizontal slider - similar to an image carousel) which contains several UIWebViews - each of which takes the whole screen. Each webview has a head-bar on top and vertically scrollable content that should scroll behind the bar if necessary. This is done in html and css with position:fixed for the head-bar.

It works fine in iOS5 but fails in iOS4. This is a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889601/css-position-fixed-into-ipad-iphone) and there are several javascript solutions for this problem, e.g. from website [doctyper](http://doctyper.com/archives/200808/fixed-positioning-on-mobile-safari/) or iScroll4 or touch-scroll (which is based on iScroll).

These solutions work nicely in regards to the vertical scrolling. My problem now is that I cannot swipe horizontally (from UIWebView to UIWebView) anymore as long as I start the swipe gesture inside the vertically scrollable div-container (which takes almost the whole screen - except for a few pixels on each side). The javascript solutions seem to prevent the gesture recognition of a horizontal swipe from UIScrollView.

I am not even sure if the solution is to be found on the objective-c side or on the javascript or html side. Any help is appreciated. Even if it is just a hint in the right direction.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/iscroll/qusOnwII_dU/yct_D8lGhTAJ). In `iscroll-lite.js` you have to uncomment line 60. And in line 225 right under

```
timestamp = e.timeStamp || Date.now();
```

you have to add the line

```
if (Math.sqrt(deltaY * deltaY) > 3) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Now I can use the scrolling aid of iscroll vertically and the iOS-scrolling horizontally.