# Safari on iPhone 3g fixed position of a button

Tags: iphone, html, css, safari

I have the following jsfiddle setup:

http://jsfiddle.net/zZDqH/

Currently it is just a button that is fixed in position at bottom:0px, you can scroll up and down the page and the button remains at the bottom of the page.

When tested in Safari on an iPhone 3G (v4.2.1) the buttons position does not remain at the bottom of the page, so when you scroll the button moves position.

Any advice on how to get this working would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position fixed is not supported in older versions of ios.

It's answered here [CSS "position: fixed;" on iPad/iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889601/css-position-fixed-into-ipad-iphone).