# Manipulating the DOM during scroll on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, scroll

I have a sticky navigation bar on my site that needs to snap back into place as the user scrolls back up. I've done this using the `scroll()` function.

But on the iPad, it qeues that function until the scroll has finished, causing the bar to sticky to the very to of the page for a second and then snap back into place.

Is there anything I can do about it? Is there currently anyway of making the iPad handle scroll events the same as other browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current versions of iOS [support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889601/css-position-fixed-into-ipad-iphone) the `position:fixed` attribute in CSS. Of course, then you're leaving Android behind.

Look into using [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) - it's designed to take the quirks of various mobile browsers into account.

Comment: Thanks Blazemonger, what's situation with Andriod and position:fixed?

Comment: From what I've read, Android 4 supports it but the more common Android 3 does not.

Comment: more common Android 3 ?