# Responsive Nav with sticking div on ios

Tags: jquery, html, css, ios

I've been after a specific navigation pattern. First I'll explain how I'd like it to behave:

If you imagine a web page with a large header or nav bar. When the page is scrolled down everything lower down on the page scrolls up whilst the header stays static underneath.

A very close example of this is here:
http://inspectelement.com/demos/responsive/mobilenav/

In fact I tried contacting the author to no avail.

If you imagine that example but when scrolled up the grey bar then fixes to the top of the screen
On scroll up the grey bar needs to detach again and start scrolling.

I've seen this work in many places and I've even built my own. The big issue is that all examples I've seen don't update immediately on iOS. The example above does and I think uses jquery animate, but I have the issue of detaching the grey bar without it jumping in ios.

If anyone can help I would be very grateful.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

The `position: fixed` css property does exactly what you are searching for I think.

edit : duplicate of this thread then ? [CSS "position: fixed;" on iPad/iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889601/css-position-fixed-into-ipad-iphone)

Comment: Yes position fixed does work, but it jumps when it's scrolled in ios. I'm after a smooth effect. Thanks anyway

Comment: I edited my post (don't know if you were ping or not :( ). You should find better answers in this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889601/css-position-fixed-into-ipad-iphone

Comment: Thanks for all that mate. I'm not sure it's going to do what I need. I'll give it a crack and if not I'll paste the code I make on jsfiddle. Mike