# Position Fixed not working in iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, css-position

I am creating a HTML page for my web site but unfortunately position fixed for top navigation menu is not working in iPhone.

Can anyone please help me ?

Cheers,

Comment: possible duplicate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889601/css-position-fixed-into-ipad-iphone). also look [here](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/17406/css-positionfixed-not-working-in-ipod/p1)

Answer (score 1):

Position:fixed was supported as of iOS 5, if you are trying or hoping to make it work on anything older ( iOs4 ) you are out of luck as it was not supported.
"iOS4 and below simply treats elements as static and scrolls them along with the rest of the page."

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem with a mobile website I made a while ago & eventually was a success!

maybe if I could take a look at your source code, look though it fix th problem and post it back here. :)