# Sticky nav menu links not working on iPad

Tags: ios, css, ipad, anchor, css-position

I have a sticky nav which becomes fixed to the top of the screen when the user scrolls down the page. It's working fine apart from on the iPad. The first time you click a link on it, it works. But after you've clicked a link once, when you click any other links they don't work.

Any ideas?

http://debourg-dev.ch/syselcloud/le-cloud-computing/

Many thanks

Comment: As an added note, Iphone does not support position:fixed, and there are no pure CSS alternatives, you may have to resort to javascript to make this work on Iphones, if you plan to

Comment: This thread is pretty comprehensive on this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889601/css-position-fixed-into-ipad-iphone