# How to create a div always floating on top For Ipad without issues?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ipad

I tried to use **position fixed** , and tested on Ipad 4 , very buggy.

1. While touch dragging on page the position fixed div sometimes **able to drag down**.
2. While zoom in/out the div **position went crazy** for a second.
3. The div is **blinking and shaking** horribly when page is scrolling down fast
4. Extremely bad performance on jquery scroll animation,create stuttering

My second attempt is to make the content inside a #container div and put the fixed object,actually a menu,outside the container and let the #container overflow-y:scroll and hidden the body overflow. Tested on Ipad 4, the problems are:

1. The momentum turned off. It means while Touch scroll ,the page moving stop instantly as user put his finger off, normally it should able to slide a bit after user finger off.
2. I tried to put  webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; for the #container, now on ipad it can slide normally but on macbook firefox browser, the scrolling is locked ,page can't move at all.
3. If I put overflow-y and webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch both, the ipad won't works , but the firefox works again.

Any advises on create a div always floating on top For Ipad without issues? I thought this should be a common problems.

Comment: Maybe you can get something out of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889601/css-position-fixed-into-ipad-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've succeeded by putting the container into `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` mode, which you claim not to be working.

Try once more:

```
#container {
  overflow:scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transform:translateZ(0px);
}
```

Comment: oh it works now I guess I typed webkit-overflow-scrolling, missing a -, holy I used a day but never could find that out