# CSS fixed position on mobile browsers

Tags: css, browser, mobile-safari

I'm not sure I can explaint clearly what is the problem, so please be understanding.

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="navbar">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
#container {
    display: block;
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
}
#navbar {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 640px;
    height: 70px;
}
#content {
    display: block;
    marign: 70px 0 0 0;
    width: 640px;
    height: 410px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

It works fine on desktop and any Android-base browser, but in iPhone's Safari... When I zoom in on this page the content works fine, but the fixed element stay on position relative to screen. Every other element moving fine.

What is the problem? I don't have idea...

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS "position: fixed;" into iPad/iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889601/css-position-fixed-into-ipad-iphone)

Answer (score -1):

[An element with fixed position is positioned relative to the browser window.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

You should give `top: 0;` and/or `left:0` etc

Answer (score -1):

try on this code http://jsfiddle.net/nandhakumarsri9/bkwLG/

```
#container {
    display: block;
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}
#navbar {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 640px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid #F00;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#content {
    display: block;
    width: 640px;
    height: 410px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px solid #00F;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Most of mobile browsers have problem with fixed positioning. Try to use jQuery mobile framework with data-position="fixed" attribute.