# iPad fixed position with input focus

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad, css-position

Whenever I give focus to an input field which is within a container that is fixed (in this case, a toolbar), an ipad will remove the fixed position. Now I can scroll above and below that toolbar, which is undesirable.

https://www.hypotheker.nl/#/afspraak-maken

I have tried many things like setting the body to a fixed position, but that will scroll the page to the top.

Does anybody have the golden solution to fix this issue?

Comment: If you dont want the page to move you can use something like `$(document).bind('touchmove', false);`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20205857/3523645

Basically, it's a known bug in touch-device browsers and the solution is to detect `focus` event on target input fields and at that moment change the styling of `fixed` elements to `position: absolute`.

The mentioned solution uses [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)'s `touch` property, but keep in mind the following (taken from modernizr's documentation):

> The `Modernizr.touch` test only indicates if the browser supports touch events, which does not necessarily reflect a touchscreen device.