# iOS 8.3 fixed HTML element disappears on input focus

Tags: html, ios, css

I have a strange situation that sounds very much like the [many fixed element issues with iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199072/ios-input-focused-inside-fixed-parent-stops-position-update-of-fixed-elements) on Stack Overflow, but with a twist.  This only happens when the parent document is scrollable.  I am also using an iframe.  Below is a representation of the HTML I am displaying

```
<body>
   /*
    main content
    */

   <div class="myCtrl"> 
     <iframe src="page2.htm"/>//iframe contains html page with an input element
     <div></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

`.myCtrl` has a style of:

```
 .myCtrl {
    max-width: none;
    max-height: 690px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 75vh;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    right: 0;
}
```

The iframe contains several input elements that when focused (and soft keyboard pops up), `.myCtrl` is pushed out of view.  If I type something, `.myCtrl` comes back in to view and is displayed correctly.  If I remove focus from an input, `.myCtrl` does NOT leave the view and correctly stays put.  The `.myCtrl` will then behave correctly, respecting `position:fixed`, for the rest of the browser session regardless if an input has focus or not.

both the parent page and the iframe have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />` in the header.

Meta tag solutions don't seem to work.

using `position:absolute` doesn't seem feasible since `.myCtrl` is not able to receive any event notifications from input focus.

`-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;` doesn't seem feasible since `.myCtrl` is appended to the body, and I have no control over the content structure.

[css font resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989263/disable-auto-zoom-in-input-text-tag-safari-on-iphone) doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this is what I came up with in order to solve it.
The issue is that the Iframe container is losing his position (mine was fixed ) and it get changed to absolute.

so I wanted it to be fixed when the keyboard is open, and make sure that the window wont scroll too much.

so here is the code:

```
window.onscroll = function () {//is called when the keyboard is open
    if (window.pageYOffset > window.innerHeight / 3) {//my decision you can play with it as you would like 
        window.scrollTo(0, window.innerHeight / 3);
        if (document.getElementById('IframeWrapperID').style.position !== 'fixed')  {
            document.getElementById('IframeWrapperID').style.position = 'fixed';
        }
    }
};
```

*My iframe had position absolute.
Hope it helped.