# CSS Fixed positioning on IOS causing choppy scrolling after zooming in and then zooming out (using fancybox)

Tags: ios, scroll, fancybox, mobile-safari, css-position

I'm using fancybox, and it seems that many people who use it disable zooming of any kind on mobile devices.  The problem is that when I have a fancybox open, completely zoom in while the fancy box is open, completely zoom out, and then close fancybox.  When I scroll the body, depending on the direction of the scroll, there is a lag where a top section or bottom section is chopped off, and then revealed after a split second delay.

I found out that removing the position fixed style from the overlay removes the issue.  I also saw that on caniuse.com that fixed positioning only has 6% support, including iOS 7.

Are there any workarounds that can fix this issue with fancybox?  Thanks.

**edit**

I found this other SO question, that might help for reference: [CSS "position: fixed;" on iPad/iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889601/css-position-fixed-into-ipad-iphone/4889871#4889871)

Answer (score 1):

On your div put:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```