# Overflow hidden not working with fixed child

Tags: html, css

So, i'm trying to create a fixed background, actually its working. The problem is with my footer, because it is set back from the main and as the user goes scrolling it is displayed. The problem is when I put the fixed image, it is in the main with overflow: hidden, however the overflow: hidden does not work.

Here is a fiddle with my concept without the image: http://jsfiddle.net/7q8v1vsu/

And here with the fixed image: http://jsfiddle.net/L4oofkso/

And finally the code:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="main-content"></div>
    <div id="main-background">
        <img src="http://clickalifecoachblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Child-Girl-Bear-Toy-Autumn-Leaves-Nature-Photo-HD-Wallpaper.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#main{
    position: relative;
    background: #749B35;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    height: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
}


#main-background{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}
#main-background > img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 1200;
    z-index: 0;
}


#footer{
    position: relative;
}
#footer-inner{
    position: fixed;
    background: #E76144;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Anyone know if this can be fixed with just CSS or I'll have to appeal to Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: do you know why `position:fixed` is used..

Comment: @NaeemShaikh Yes, I want the background to be fixed, but I can not make it to interact with the overflow: hidden

Comment: are you trying to display the footer on the bottom of the fixed background?

Comment: @ErycBrown When scroll occurs the #footer is fixed and #main has a margin-bottom: 70px and overflow:hidden. #main-background is fixed inside #main and the #main overflow:hidden is not hiding #main-background, this is the problem...

Answer (score 1):

If it is a fixed background, why aren't you using a proper fixed background? http://jsfiddle.net/L4oofkso/1/

```
#main{
    position: relative;
    background: #749B35;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    height: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
    background: url("http://clickalifecoachblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Child-Girl-Bear-Toy-Autumn-Leaves-Nature-Photo-HD-Wallpaper.jpg") center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Of course it works, you just need to expand that css: http://jsfiddle.net/L4oofkso/3/

Comment: @JonasGrumann the problem happens in mobile browsers, either in iOS and android...

Comment: If you want position fixed on all mobiles you're going to have a bad time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889601/css-position-fixed-into-ipad-iphone

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/7q8v1vsu/

Using `background-attachment: fixed;` will provide you with the desired results.