# fixed header not work in IOS but in android and pc everything is ok

Tags: ios, css, iphone, scroll, header

i have a div fixed to wrap, and in this div i have a sticky header fixed to top,
sticky header work well on android and pc ,
but not working in IOS .

```
Js Fiddle :   http://jsfiddle.net/k2R3G/452/
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889601/css-position-fixed-into-ipad-iphone

Comment: i looked at this before, but not work

Comment: I too have the same problem. here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r5cnbm3o/ this works fine in pc and android but in ios not works