# Keep footer on top on iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, css, position, touchscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fixed positioning in Mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743123/fixed-positioning-in-mobile-safari)

Hi,

i'm creating a small iPhone html5 app. I would like to keep a footer-div on the bottom of the screen and on top of the rest of the content. It works perfect with this css in my desktop browser:

```
#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

But when I scroll it on my iPhone, it doesn't work, the #footer div stays on that exact position. So I tried a fix with jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    position = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("#footer").css("bottom",-position+"px");
});
```

Ok, so this works in a way on the iPhone, but it only works when I release my finger of the touchscreen. So it doesn't work **while** i'm scrolling (sliding my finger on the touchscreen)...

Anybody has some experience with this? Additional I can mention that this would not be gapped to a native app, so any "web"-solutions are welcome!

Thanks!