# css / jquery - need persistent footer without using position:fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am programming a mobile site and I want an element to be fixed at a certain position on the screen and stay there even as the user scrolls down the page. I can't use position:fixed as far as I know because iPhone doesn't support it. How would I accomplish this? I do not want to use jquery mobile.

Comment: Probably helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743123/fixed-positioning-in-mobile-safari

Comment: You mean that the element must stay visible for the user?

Comment: Yes - it must always be visible at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im ganna start off by saying iOS5 will have support for fixed.
but for now, you're ganna have to use javascript to move it.
Lets assume ur footer's ID is "myFooter"

```
window.addEventListener(
  'scroll',
  function() {
    document.getElementById('myFooter').style.top = 
    (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - footerHeight) + 'px';
  },
  false
);
```

that should move it when you scroll (footerHeight is your footer's height and can also be retrieved with `document.getElementById("myFooter").style.height` if the style object was used to define the height

If there is something I have not forseen in the above solution, you can always divide the viewport into two sections, the content and footer. Just absolutely position the footer and use the touch events (`touchmove`,`touchend`,`targetTouches` etc) in combination with `scrollTo` (scrollTo(destination, duration)) on your content area

Answer (score 2):

you might want to make use of jquery mobile, in particular check out the section "persistent footer navigation bar"

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html