# How to create device-fixed containers?

Tags: jquery, css, iphone, ipad, responsive-design

I've got `position:fixed;` container and it is always fixed when I sroll page on PC (remains on the top left corner).

On iPhone it appears on the top left corner but it stays there forever as I scroll. Is there any solution to that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6273183/1182904

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>The best option here seems Media Queries, see: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ and http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries for examples.</s>

edit: Miss read the question:

As Josh' link suggests you can achieve this by:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  document.getElementById('fixedDiv').style.top =
    (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - 25) + 'px';
};
```

Comment: Looks like position: fixed; will be supported in iOS 5. I'll use your solution for iPhone 2G and iPhone 3G.