# responsive CSS - How to I make padding adjust automatically when visiting my site with an iPhone?

Tags: css

Here is the link to my site:
daisy.camorada.com
within the `<style>` tag there is this:

```
body {
padding-top: 60px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.sidebar-nav {
padding: 9px 0;
}
```

I have this so that the information in the  will not be behind the navbar at the top, however, as you can see with the screenshot image below, when i visit my site with an iPhone, the padding at the top (i think that is the problem) is way too much as it pushes down the navbar.

How can I make the navbar appear at the top in both normal browsers & the iphone?!
I don't think that it is a conflict issue with my other .css files. Thanks in advance for your help!

[screenshot of both iphone and normal browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imUug.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the iPhone deals with padding differently(/stupidly). You want to remove the Body padding and replace it with:

```
top:60px;
position:absolute;
```

Comment: try applying it to the style for the "container-fluid" class instead of the body - so have nothing there for the body, you may want to increase top to 80px as well

Comment: have you tried looking through @thirender 's link - not the best but might also work

Comment: I inserted that into the class you mentioned, no luck. see daisy.camorada.com thanks

Comment: for some reason in firefox it isn't looking great either

Comment: I think that i fixed it using:

.navbar {
  *position: relative;
  *z-index: 2;
  overflow: visible;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
 top:60px; /* rid of it */
 position:absolute; /* rid of it */
}

Comment: Does that look good to you now? I'm not a pro with CSS but it looks great to me. Thank you for your continued help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that iOS doesn't have support for `position: fixed;` until iOS 5. See [Fixed positioning in Mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743123/fixed-positioning-in-mobile-safari). You'll have to use `position: absolute;` along with some `@media` queries to selectively apply styles to mobile browsers.